# DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated. Use messageCreate instead

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I am relatively new to discord bots but I cant for the life of me figure out why I keep getting this error - I have tried to replace message with message creat but it doesn't seem to work at all.
Here is my code:

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if(message.author.client) return; 
    if(message.channel.type !== 'text') return;
    let prefix = '!'; 
    let MessageArray = message.content.split(' ');
    let cmd = MessageArray(0).slice(prefix.length)
    let args = MessageArray.slice(1)

    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return; 

    if(cmd == 'hello') {
        message.channel.send({ messages: ['hello'] });
    })
```

Comment: The error couldn't be anymore straight foward: *use messageCreate instead*

Comment: A warning is not an error.

Answer (score 4):

The `message` event has been renamed to `messageCreate`. Using `message` will still work, but you'll receive a deprecation warning until you switch over.

---

```js
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.author.client) return;
    if (message.channel.type !== "text") return;
    let prefix = "!";
    let MessageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let cmd = MessageArray(0).slice(prefix.length);
    let args = MessageArray.slice(1);

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    if (cmd == "hello") {
        message.channel.send({ messages: ["hello"] });
    }
});
```