# Error Message: (node:12160) and problem with an await function

Tags: discord, discord.js

My Problem is that I'm getting the following error Message:

`` (node:12160) DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated.  Use messageCreate instead(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created) ``

I know that there's a solution for this on this Site but my problem is that my `await` function is not working when I try to change the `.send({ embeds: [embed] })` to `message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });` and i don't know how to change the embed so my `await` function is working and the error resolves.

```js
    if (message.content.startsWith("!Suggestion")) {
        var str = message.content.slice(" !Suggestion".length);

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setThumbnail('Png')
            .setTitle("Suggestion")
            .setColor('#151515')
            .addFields(
                { name: "Person, with a suggestion:", value: `<@!${message.author.id}>` },
                { name: 'Suggestion:', value: `${str}` },
                { name: 'Channel:', value: `${message.channel}` },
            )
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter("You can vote for the suggestion with the emojis on the bottom")


        await message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'Suggestion')
           .send({ embeds: [embed] })
           .then(embedMessage => {
                embedMessage.react("✅")
                embedMessage.react("❌")
            });
        message.delete();
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated. Use messageCreate instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68989068/deprecationwarning-the-message-event-is-deprecated-use-messagecreate-instead)

Comment: Define clearer "my await function is not working". What error produces? What is the intended and what the observed behavior?
Also, what you got is a warning, not an error, and it seems to be not originated from this chunk of code. So, for that, I suggest you to do what the warning say, that is to use node to find the deprecation

Comment: Furthermore, try to focus more: it is the warning your problem or it is the `await` function? Edit your title to represent the question you're asking, to focus it more

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you updated to Discord.js V13 and there are a lot of changes.

The warning you get is about the on message event.

On v12 it was:

```js
client.on("message", ...);
```

and now on v13 it is:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", ...);
```

Check https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html for all the changes in the newest version.
You will have to update your code according to the changes.